# Can't hear any sound with ion.sound on Firefox/Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, audio, plugins

I'm having trouble with using with plugin, even if the code is quite simple, my browser can't seem to play anything :(

- Some context :

  - Computer is a laptop with windows 10
  - Browsers are Firefox 43.0.4 and Chrome 48.smthg

and code looks like this

- sounds.js

  ```
  // init bunch of sounds
  ion.sound({
      sounds: [
          {
              name: "beer_can_opening",
              ended_callback: function () {
                  console.log("ended")
              },
              ready_callback: function () {
                  console.log("ready")
              }
          },
          {name: "bell_ring"},
          {name: "branch_break"},
          {name: "button_click"}
      ],

      // main config
      path: "sounds/",
      preload: true,
      multiplay: true,
      volume: 0.9,
      loop: 10
  });

  // play sound
  ion.sound.play("beer_can_opening");
  ```
- index.html

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html>
  <head>
      <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="ion.sound.min.js"></script>
      <script src="sounds.js"></script>
      <script src="sorcery.js"></script>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
      <meta lang="fr" xml:lang="fr" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
      <title>Sword & Sorcery</title>
  </head>
  ```
- Finally the folder sounds is there, beer_can_opening.aac/ogg/mp3 too.
- In both browser's console I'm getting "ready" but not "ended" not matter how long I wait
- No other errors whatsoever :(
- The demo at http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.sound/en.html (like any other demos the author posted ) work great

Help greatly appreciated, this plugin should do the work nicely, I'd really like to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

This was an autoplay bug. Was fixed in latest release: https://github.com/IonDen/ion.sound/issues/71

Comment: Thanks, too bad my project it's done without it :(
Resolved then